# Tensorflow Model prediction output is always [0. 1.]

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I trained my pre-trained model(densenet-121) with my dataset for binary image classification. When I use test_generator results of test_generator look good but when I run my code for prediction I get the output of `[0. 1.]` How can I solve this problem?

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model

img = 
load_image('C:/Users/yurtt/Desktop/orkun/a/b/dataset/test2/not/159.png')

# predict the class
result = model.predict(img)
print(result[0])
```

output:

```
[0. 1.]
```

my model:

```
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet121

base_model = DenseNet121(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_tensor=Input(shape=input_shape))
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(1024, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = Dense(512, kernel_regularizer=l2(0.0001), bias_regularizer=l2(0.0001))(x)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = Activation("relu")(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)
prediction = Dense(output_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=prediction)
```

Comment: Where did you define `output_classes`?

Comment: I defined at the begining simply by 'output_classes = 2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `output_classes = 2`. On the other hand, the prediction as an output layer is defined to `prediction = Dense(output_classes, activation=tf.nn.softmax)(x)`. Hence, the output of the prediction has dimension 2. You can keep it as it is, but you need to transform target values to `[0 1]` and `[1 0]` that mean it is in the class `2` and class `1`, respectively.

Note that, you can also, set `output_classes` to `1` to keep target values as `0` and `1`.

Comment: I am sorry I am really new to this. How can I transform that exactly?

Comment: @orkayu no problem at all. Just write a function that returns `[1 0]` for class `1` and `[0 1]` for class `2`. Instead, you can also change the `output_classes` to `1` as well.

Comment: but my output is always `[0. 1.]` and when I change `output_classes` to `1` I get a `InvalidArgumentError: var and grad do not have the same shape[1] [2] [[node SGD/SGD/update_375/ResourceApplyKerasMomentum (defined at <ipython-input-64-fdabcda87caf>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_81906]` error

Comment: @orkayu So, you have already transformed the target value to `[0 1]` and `[1 0]`.

Comment: okey but now I am getting output like `[7.1084955e-06 9.9999285e-01]`. What does that mean?

Comment: @orkayu Now you can have different strategies for interpretation of the result. For example, for an output `[a b]`, you can interpret it as class `1` if `a > b`, and class `2`, otherwise.